# Convert flat array of delimited strings (filepaths) to a hierarchical, associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data, directory-structure

I have a collection of keys in this massive flat single array I would like to basically expand that array into a multidimensional one organized by keys - here is an example:

Input:

```
[
    'invoice/products/data/item1',
    'invoice/products/data/item2',
    'invoice/products/data/item2',
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'invoice' => [
        'products' => ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
    ]
]
```

How can I do this?

The length of the above strings are variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines: <strike>(Didn't test it though!)</strike> Works now ;)

```
$data = array();
$current = &$data;
foreach($keys as $value) {
  $parts = explode("/", $value);
  $parts_count = count($parts);
  foreach($parts as $i => $part) {
    if(!array_key_exists($part, $current)) {
      if($i == $parts_count - 1) {
        $current[] = $part;
      }
      else {
        $current[$part] = array();
        $current = &$current[$part];
      }
    }
    else {
      $current = &$current[$part];
    }
  }
  $current = &$data;
}
```

*$keys* beeing the flat array.

Answer (score 5):

```
$src = array(
'invoice/products/data/item1',
'invoice/products/data/item2',
'invoice/products/data/item2',
'foo/bar/baz',
'aaa/bbb'
);

function rsplit(&$v, $w)
{
    list($first, $tail) = explode('/', $w, 2);
    if(empty($tail)) 
    {
        $v[] = $first;
        return $v;
    }
    $v[$first] =  rsplit($v[$first], $tail);
    return $v;

}

$result = array_reduce($src, "rsplit");
print_r($result);
```

Output is: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SmYC7))

```
Warning: rsplit(): Argument #1 ($v) must be passed by reference, value given

Warning: Undefined array key 1

Warning: rsplit(): Argument #1 ($v) must be passed by reference, value given

Warning: Undefined array key 1

Warning: rsplit(): Argument #1 ($v) must be passed by reference, value given

Warning: Undefined array key 1

Warning: rsplit(): Argument #1 ($v) must be passed by reference, value given

Warning: Undefined array key 1

Warning: rsplit(): Argument #1 ($v) must be passed by reference, value given

Warning: Undefined array key 1
Array
(
    [invoice] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => item1
                            [1] => item2
                            [2] => item2
                        )

                )

        )

    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [0] => baz
                )

        )

    [aaa] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbb
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted @LevonMirzoyan's snippet so that `array_reduce()` works with modern versions of PHP.

> [PHP 8.0.0    `If callback expects a parameter to be passed by reference, this function will now emit an E_WARNING.`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php#:%7E:text=If%20callback%20expects%20a%20parameter%20to%20be%20passed%20by%20reference%2C%20this%20function%20will%20now%20emit%20an%20E_WARNING.)

I prefer to use `sscanf()` to parse the input string while traversing because it isolates the two halves of the string and counts the generated elements in one step. Bear in mind `%s` will not be suitable if there are spaces in the string. **If dealing with spaces in the input strings, then go back to using `explode()` and `count()`.**

The null coalescing assignment declaration conveniently/concisely creates an empty array when needed -- just before traversing the next level.

Using `(__FUNCTION__)` offers the flexibility to change the function name by only changing the head of the function instead of needing to change the name in two places.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CUbUQ))

```
function hydratePath(array $result, ?string $path): array
{
    if (sscanf($path ?? '', '%[^/]/%s', $first, $rest) < 2) {
        $result[] = $first ?? $path;
    } else {
        $result[$first] ??= [];
        $result[$first] = (__FUNCTION__)($result[$first], $rest);
    }
    return $result;
}

$array = [
    'invoice/products/data/item1',
    '',
    null,
    'invoice/products/data/item2',
    'invoice/products/filename',
    'invoice/products/data/item2',
    'foo/bar/baz',
    '',
    'aaa/bbb'
];

var_export(array_reduce($array, "hydratePath", []));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'invoice' => 
  array (
    'products' => 
    array (
      'data' => 
      array (
        0 => 'item1',
        1 => 'item2',
        2 => 'item2',
      ),
      0 => 'filename',
    ),
  ),
  0 => '',
  1 => NULL,
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'bar' => 
    array (
      0 => 'baz',
    ),
  ),
  2 => '',
  'aaa' => 
  array (
    0 => 'bbb',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not clear from your question how the "/" separated strings will map to an array, the basic approach will probably be something like this:

```
$result = array();
$k1 = $k2 = '';
ksort($yourData); // This is the key (!)
foreach ($yourData as $k => $v) {
  // Use if / else if / else if to watch for new sub arrays and change
  // $k1, $k2 accordingly
  $result[$k1][$k2] = $v;
}
```

This approach uses the ksort to ensure that keys at the same "level" appear together, like this:

```
'invoice/products/data1/item1'
'invoice/products/data1/item2'
'invoice/products/data2/item3'
'invoice/products2/data3/item4'
'invoice/products2/data3/item5'
```

Notice how the ksort corresponds to the key grouping you're aiming for.